# Dump a Mongo data base in one csv file

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, pandas, pymongo

I would like to dump the data of a Mongo data base on one csv/excel file. 
My database have several documents with the same fields and embedded fields. I want each embedded field to be one column of my csv file, and each document one line. 
Here is the goal :

```
a_cursor = a_collection.find(filter, projection)  # pymongo.collection.find() method
a_csv_file = print_cursor_to_csv(a_cursor,projection)  # the method I would like to create
```

- With the filter argument of find(), I will be able to filter the mongo documents.
- With the projection argument of find(), I will choose the fields to put in csv columns.
- The projection argument is used again in print_cursor_to_csv(), this time just to give the order of the fields/columns for the csv file. Indeed, projection is a list of fields, and the first field will be the first csv column.

Here is the method I wrote :

```
def _print_cursor_in_csv(cursor, fields_to_show_order):
    """

    :param cursor: pymongo.Cursor. The list of documents to print into csv.
    :param fields_to_show_order: List of String. Permits to know the order of columns chosen by the user.
            Example : BaseStation_ID as first columns, then frequency of utilisation etc..
    """
    flattened_cursor = []
    for a_document in cursor:
        flattened_cursor.append(_flatten_the_dict(a_document))
    string_csv = _get_string_csv_from_list_of_dicts(flattened_cursor, fields_to_show_order)
    _write_a_file_from_a_string("testCSV"+".csv", string_csv)  # PRINT CSV OF A DOC
```

My method works but is big and I would like to rely more on python libraries such as pandas, openpyxl or csv. Perhaps one of them can write a csv file from a list of dictionaries after flattening each one of them.

Thank you for your help,

Matias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongoexport to do this. Here is an example which dumps all data form database test in collection traffic to a csv file. (Starting version 3.0. mongo removed the  --csv option plase use the --type=csv)

```
mongoexport --db test --collection traffic --type=csv --out traffic.csv
```

in case you like to shrink the number of records you can do this by querying the data you want to dump. Just add a query with -q e.g.:

```
--query '{"field": 1}'
```

In case you only want some field(s) to be exported the you can add the following option (with csv you have to provide a field list):

```
--fields <field1,field2>
```

Please make sure that there is no space after the comma. Fields with white-space will still be comma seperated with no leading or tailing space but you have to put the complete list into quotes (the documentation is a little bit unclear on this).

If you want to get a special field which is embedded you can address this by:

```
--fields "field1,toplevelFieldName.0.field2"
```

Please note that there is a "0" as index for the element. monogexport can not export all elements top an csv so you either need to address them one by one, which is unrealistic. Or you use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to save the data to a further collection which you then can export.

**OR** in case you do not mind to get the complete embedded document you can use:

```
-- fields "field1,toplevelFieldName"
```

toplevelFieldName is the name of the embedded document.

A complete documentation on mongoexport can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/).

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed much easier. I have two extra questions :

While trying to authenticate with mongoexport --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1, I get the error : `2017-01-13T09:25:27.625+0100 User Assertion: 2:SCRAM-SHA-1 mechanism support not compiled into client library.` I have mongoexport 2.6.10. Second question: in my database I have some fields which are lists of dictionaries, each dictionary having the same two fields, x and y. I would like to export those data so as to get x values in columns headers and y values in the related cells for each document. Thanks again

Comment: Since Version 3.0 MongoDB no longer defaults to MONGODB-CR and instead uses SCRAM-SHA-1 as the default authentication mechanism. You can use `--authenticationMechanism MONGODB-CR`for older versions